# Laravel dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd/ conversion while using Model for DB Operations

Tags: php, date, laravel, laravel-4, model

**Here is my Controller**

```
public function DriverProcess()
    {            
     $DriverData = Input::all();
     $validation = Validator::make($DriverData, DriverModel::$rules);
     if ($validation->passes())
        {
            DriverModel::create($DriverData);
     //Rest of Code
```

**Here is my Model**

```
<?php
class DriverModel extends Eloquent 
{


    protected $guarded = array('DriverName');
    protected $fillable = array('DriverName', 'Age', 'Address', 'LicenseNumber', 'DateOfBirth', 'LicenseExpiry' );
```

In the field `DateOfBirth` and `LicenseExpiry`

I send the Values of Date as `dd/mm/yyyy`  Format

As i am sending the using Model `DriverModel::create($DriverData);` and using `fillable` I don't know where to convert the `dd/mm/yyyy` to `yyyy/mm/dd`

**Note :**

I know to convert the date format by `date("Y-m-d", strtotime($var) );` But i need to know where i can do this operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use mutators for this in your model (see http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators). In your case, that would be:

```
public function setDateOfBirthAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['DateOfBirth'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($value) );
}
```

As a sidenote, you should only use `$fillable` or `$guarded` in your model. Right now, you have the same attribute set in both `$guarded` and `$fillable`.